# cannot execute scripts through cypher-shell

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to execute these queries within Cypher-shell environment:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///names.csv' AS row
WITH row.Fname AS first, row.Lname AS last
MERGE (p:la {last: last})
MERGE (o:fi {first: first})
MERGE (c:central {name: "central node"})
MERGE (c)-[r:CONTAINS {first:first}]->(o)-[rel:CONTAINS {first: first}]->(p)
RETURN count(o)
```

I have saved these queries inside a file named "cypher.ex1" and I'm using this command to execute it:

```
neo4j@neo4j> :source cypher.ex1
```

but nothing happens. I added ";" to the end of all queries like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///names.csv' AS row;

WITH row.Fname AS first, row.Lname AS last;

MERGE (p:la {last: last});

MERGE (o:fi {first: first});

MERGE (c:central {name: "central node"});

MERGE (c)-[r:CONTAINS {first:first}]->(o)-[rel:CONTAINS {first: first}]->(p);

RETURN count(o);
```

I receive this error:

```
Query cannot conclude with LOAD CSV (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 2, column 60 (offset: 60))
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///subdomainIP.csv' AS row;"
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must only use a semicolon at the end of a Cypher *statement*, not at the end of every clause.

A Cypher statement usually has a `RETURN` clause at the end, but it can also end with a clause that writes to the DB (e.g., a `CREATE` clause) if there is nothing that needs to be returned.

In your particular file, you really only have a single Cypher statement, so delete all the semicolons except the last one.